# How to Solve "The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly" error without updating xamarin.forms version

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am stuck in one of my issue in xamarin.forms. In my xamarin.form project xamarin.form package version is 2.3.2.123 in PCL,Android and IOS.

Since Last few days when I am trying to build my iphone project, its gives me an error

> The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly

So I have updated xamarin.form version in PCL, Droid and IOS.

but due to this I am facing issue in Android in one of my page

> {Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isMutable()' on a null object
>   reference   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    …}

I am using

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

Instead

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

because I want to scroll page even when keyboard is open. If keyboard is open then page can't be scroll in android this is the bug of "App Compact".

Now I don't understand what should I do?

**Is there any other way to solve "The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly" error without updating xamarin.forms version.**

because all the issues arise due to xamarin.forms updation.

**In one of other project I am using same xamarin.forms version but it works perfectly. What is actual reason of "XamlC task failed" error?**

Answer (score 0):

Although the cause seems different, it looks like it's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55559). Maybe you could verify that upgrading to the version mentioned in the bug (2.3.5-pre) works for you, and then either disable XAML compilation for the time being, or work with the Xamarin pre-release packages.

Comment: I don't want to use FormAppCompact activity because as mention above AppCompact having bug "When keyboard is open page can't scroll" This bug is due to AppCompact. Client has strong requirement that page has to scroll.